# Can't resolve module 'react-redux' in connected-react-router with react-redux and redux modules installed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, connected-react-router

I'm trying to use `connected-react-router` module.

From the docs, this is my code in the reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import login from './loginReducer';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

export default (history) => combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  login
});
```

I'm getting this error in compilation time:

> ./node_modules/connected-react-router/esm/ConnectedRouter.js Module
>   not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux' in
>   'C:\Users\ericn\Documents\ReactJS\test\node_modules\connected-react-router\esm'

I've been looking for this for a while but none seems to have the same problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you importing something from react-redux?

Answer (score 6):

I recently experience a similar error. What I realized was that I forgot to add `react-redux` as a dependency to my project, I only added `react`.

So confirm that you have `react-redux` in your package.json and it is installed in your node_modules. If not you can run:

```
npm install --save react-redux

// or if you are using yarn
yarn add react-redux
```